# Use case for jQuery Global Ajax Event Handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm currently studying the jQuery ajax methods and trying to take a little more in-depth look into them.  I was playing with the global event handlers: `ajaxStart`, `ajaxSend`, etc. I understand how they work, but I can't think of any good use cases for them.

I've seen examples where they are used for loggers which seems feasible enough, but why make them methods and not stand alone functions that can be called like `$.ajax()`.  It seems if I don't have any particular element to attach them to I just set it to the `$(document)` anyway.

Also, being able to use `$(this)` inside of the handlers does not seem like much of a benefit over just doing `$("#log")`.

Have these been a life savor for anyone, are there any other use cases outside of a global logger?

Answer (score 1):

The global event handlers are useful for showing indicators to the user as well. That way their experience is consistent (same indicators when saving/loading) and you don't have to write the same code over and over.

Answer (score 1):

The ajaxError method is great for global ajax error handling.  Instead of having an error callback on all of your ajax calls, you can use the global and have it log somewhere.  You can access all the information from the original ajax call from ajaxError.

Answer (score 0):

- `$(this)` insead of `$('div span.foo div[data-foo="foo"] > input.EVIL')` or `$('*')`can be a life saver...
  It depends on the exact scenario, but it ALWAYS better and a good practice...
- And the case you want for the ajaxsetup:  [Pass the same options to a jQuery function over and over](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9812788/601179)
  Here is a guy that this option helped him out.